# getting unrecognized character in notepad

Tags: format

i am trying to open this file format so that i can do some automation for it.
[https://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/Embroidery_format_PES#:~:text=The%20PES%20format%20is%20a%20hybrid%20embroidery%20design,two%20different%20parts%20for%20two%20completely%20different%20purposes](https://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/Embroidery_format_PES#:%7E:text=The%20PES%20format%20is%20a%20hybrid%20embroidery%20design,two%20different%20parts%20for%20two%20completely%20different%20purposes).
However, when i try to open it funny characters emerge [image: funny characters]

i am very new to reading file format and wondering if there is any library / text editor i can use to read the format?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.sewingmachinefun.com/best-free-embroidery-software-digitizing/.  This is badly off-topic for Stack Overflow, so I'm voting to close.

Comment: Dear sir. Thank you for the answer. However, I do have that software. The software is working fine, ihave no problem using the software. It is known as pe design. What i want to do is to hack that file so that i can do some automation of it. Probably create different design on the fly, using AI. That is why i need to read the file using external programming language...

Comment: Well, the link that you posted describes the file format in detail.  If you're going to hack one of these files, then an editor for it is not what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the very fast answer. Then, if an editor is not what i am looking for, can you tell me what tool can i use to start tinkering this file?

Comment: You want to just tinker with it?  Or you want to automate changes to it?  If you're looking to automate, as your earlier comment suggested, you'll have to write a program to make the changes you want.  If you just want to tinker a little, then EITHER use one of the editors mentioned on the page that I linked to in my first comment, OR use a hex editor such as HxD or WinHex.